# Difference between Bucket_DISPLAY_NAME and DISPLAY_NAME of an image

Tags: android

What is the difference between `BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME` and `DISPLAY_NAME` of an image? What exactly is a bucket?

Answer (score 2):

I found it out after testing.

`BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME` refers to the folder that the image is located in.

`DISPLAY_NAME` is the name of the image file.